# Callback error when trying to create speech recognition game

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I'm trying to create a voice based adventure game and when I get to the "knife" choice the code is giving this error:

```
Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function catch_errors.<locals>.call_with_this at 0x000001A0AEB6F1F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Cybineer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\comtypes\_comobject.py", line 91, in call_with_this
  File "C:\Users\Cybineer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1474, in error
  File "C:\Users\Cybineer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1699, in isEnabledFor
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Source code:

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
import time
import pyttsx3
from playsound import playsound
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import sys

engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[1].id)
engine.setProperty("rate", 150)
engine.say(" As you head down the dark alleyway the light you saw quickly gets further and further away and you then notice 2 doors.")
time.sleep(a)
engine.say("Say Left or Say Right")
engine.runAndWait()

listener = sr.Recognizer()
print("listening...")

try:
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        listener.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        voice = listener.listen(source)
        command = listener.recognize_google(voice)
        command = command.lower()

        if "left" in command:
            engine.say(" You think just because this path isn't as dark it is safer. But you may be in for a suprise.")
            time.sleep(a)
            engine.say(" The door opens and you are faced with the brightest light you have ever seen.")
            time.sleep(3)
            engine.say("GAME OVER")
            engine.runAndWait()
            city = False



        elif "right" in command:
            engine.say(" You are headed down a dark path but the reward may be great!!")
            time.sleep(a)
            engine.say("Say Knife or Say Bow and Arrow to choose your weapon: ")
            listener = sr.Recognizer()
            engine.runAndWait()
            print("listening...")

            


            if "knife" in command:
                engine.say(" You pick up the knife and notice it already has dried blood on it. Who's blood is this you wonder.")
                time.sleep(a)
                engine.say(" You head further into the dark room and you hear very faintly your name being called. {}........{}..... Please come help me".format(name, name))
                time.sleep(a)
                engine.say("Say voice to head towards the voice or Say room to keep exploring the room: ")
                listener = sr.Recognizer()
                engine.runAndWait()
                print("listening...")
```

Comment: Can you please reduce your code to a [mre] and add the required import statements?

Comment: I've added the requested information

Comment: Thanks, and where exactly does the error occur? Can you please add the error traceback?

Comment: I've add the the traceback from the new error I am getting. Now when i say left or right the callback error happens

Comment: @mkrieger1  what do you think I could be doing wrong?